# Reagarding skype for linux 32bit machine

Tags: command-line

How and from where can I download skype for ubuntu 16.04 32bit machine and how can I install it?

Comment: Skype no longer supports the 32-bit version. SkypeforLinux is now 64-bit only

Answer (score 0):

Currently Microsoft only maintains Skype for 64bit linux as most computers are now 64bit compatible. You can try to install Ubuntu 64bit and then download Skype for 64bit from www.skype.com or use the Skype web app. Note that an older 32 bit version of Skype will not work as the Skype server will reject its requests.